# Proposal for regular activities

Tags: discussion, community

This idea has been on my mind for some time, so here goes.

Let us get together every second¹ Saturday² at 1800 CET³ for several hours to do one of the following (fixed beforehand) collaboratively:

1. Answer unanswered questions.
2. Ask and answer questions in a preselected field.
3. Write tag wikis.
4. Do cleanup work (voting, retagging, flagging, editing (images!), ...); maybe focus on some tags.
5. Whatever topic we desire!

I can offer a Teamspeak server for easier and more personal communication. Furthermore, we can use one of the many online whiteboards (for instance [this](http://www.scriblink.com/)) for tinkering.

---

1. Open for discussion
2. Imho the only feasible day (usually no work, not Family Day)
3. So it is an evening event for Europeans and morning/noon activity for Americans. I do not know of many regulars in Asian timezones; if necessary, we should alternate between several times (1000,1800,0200 CET?).

Answer (score 2):

There has not been any response here, so I'll take a shot and announce a first installation.

Our ratio of [unanswered questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) has risen to uncomfortable levels (over 10%). So let's meet next

> Saturday, June 16th, around 11am CEST¹

in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science) to check out unanswered questions and collaboratively

- answer,
- improve or
- close² them.

Maybe we will even create some follow-up questions. I expect to be there till around 5pm CEST, but that's certainly no reason to stop.

I hope to see many of you in chat then. See you on Saturday!

---

Three people [attended the event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/conversation/answer-meeting-i-june-6th-2012) and contributed answers ([jmad](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/82/jmad), [Dmitri Chubarov](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/1185/dmitri-chubarov) and [myself](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/98/raphael)), namely

- [Building ideal skip lists](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/building-ideal-skip-lists/2391#2391)
- [Master theorem not applicable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/master-theorem-not-applicable/2388#2388)
- [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) (three new answers!)
- [Reduction to equipartition problem from the partition problem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/reduction-to-equipartition-problem-from-the-partition-problem/2387#2387)
- [How to describe algorithms, prove and analyse them?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/how-to-describe-algorithms-prove-and-analyse-them/2390#2390)

Obviously we did not make a dent into the unanswered question statistics given the manpower, but I think we did well. Instead of actually digging through the list of closed questions, we tackled questions we had on our minds to deserve more/better answers, and as it turned out that kept us busy for the day. Imagine what ten or fifteen users with two answers each could do!

Please let me know what made you *not* join in so we can make future instances more attractive.

---

1. That's 9am UCT, 5am EDT, 2am PDT -- sorry NA folks, but I have other plans on Saturday evening. Just join in when you wake up and keep it going.
2. I *expect* that *most* questions which can not be answered or improved to be close-worthy. I do *not* suggest to make that a general rule or anything!

Comment: Hah, maybe I'll pull an all-nighter for that (Pacific time). One way or the other, looking forward to it.

Comment: I have "borrowed" the specifics of your event as a potential prototype for a similar activity that we were thinking about starting on [CogSci.SE](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/367/31).  Hope you don't mind!

Comment: @jonsca: Not at all, I got [the](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/keeping-on-top-of-the-unanswered-questions/) [idea](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/a-regular-answer-the-unanswered-slot/) from tex.SE! :D

Comment: If you can, please prepare a list of questions you would like to tackle in particular!

Comment: [For me and the other lazy ones that don't know how to tell the time](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?iso=20120616T11&p1=48) I won't be there that long though.