# Percentage of answered questions

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

For a long time now, the statistics of the number of answered questions has been standing on 88%, slightly below the golden standard of 90%. That might be due to a lot of early questions which have not been answered. Do we want to tackle this problem by answering old unanswered questions?

Comment: note that some questions are technically considered "unanswered" because they have answer(s) with no upvotes so merely upvoting the existing answer will "answer" those.

Comment: On a related topic, we should also try to increase the number of answers per questions. For some questions this is un-doable  (like [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3554/157) or [that](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3103/157)), but sometimes giving another explanation is very helpful, and although a full answer exists, another one can be added. Maybe it will not add other information, but it could add a different point of view or use different method to explain..

Comment: For what it's worth, [all sciency sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science-users) have answer rates of around 90%, and most lower. This is not surprising and not a problem, imho. We are even better than three (of four) non-beta science sites. So while we should certainly strive to answer as many questions as possible, we don't have to worry too much about the figures.

Comment: whats "gold launched"? is there a pg on that?

Comment: @vzn "gold launched" means "went gold" means "went out of beta". I don't know what you mean by "pg".

Comment: Going over old questions, a lot of them have answers by Tsuyoshi Ito as comments.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Good job, thanks!

Comment: suggest people visit chat regularly to talk about unanswered questions, attempt to identify frequent themes/topics etc.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest we perform another event in which we should take care of unanswered questions.

A possible agenda would be:

1. Question that do have answers but those are not-upvoted. Can those answers be verified/improved and upvoted?
2. Quesitons that have comments that give a possible/partial answer - convert comments into an answer (CW answer?).
3. Questions that are cross-posted - consider closing (especially if answered in the sister SE).
4. Re-examine the other questions: clarify if not clear, close if off-topic, etc.
5. Finally, promote good questions that are still unanswered:

   - Make those question pop-up to the front page by making a small edit, or is there another way?).
   - Optionally, set bounties to the most interesting questions.

Any other suggestions?

Ideally, this should be repeated every 4-6 months.

Comment: Agreed! Are you up for planning/preparing the event? I am a bit swamped these days.

Comment: @Raphael OK, I'll try to arrange it. I'll open a chat to discuss the details.

Comment: Nudge; any progress?

Comment: There was a somewhat successful event in January. Maybe it's time for another one, But I will not have the time to arrange it. Any takers?

Comment: My bad, I did not remember the January event. Sorry! Can you open a new question for a new event, given that you were the organiser of the last? Nobody will read here, that's for sure.

Comment: this would be a good idea.. there are just too many "unaccepted" questions lying around. Many of them have good answers.

Comment: btw out of curiosity, how does the accepted answer and up-voted answer impact the Site Self-Evaluation?

Answer (score 8):

Sure. Answering unanswered questions is always a good thing.

You can find questions with no positive-score answer on the [“Unanswered” tab](https://cs.stackexchange.com/unanswered) or the similar [“unanswered” subtab of the “Questions” tab](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). (Don't forget to go back to the [Questions/newest](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) or [Questions/active](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) tab to see all questions.) You can search for questions with no answer at all with [`answers:0`](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0).

There may be questions that go unanswered because they're off-topic, or so poorly worded that we can't tell what's being asked. If you find such a question, vote to close or flag it. I think most of our unanswered questions are fine though.

CS is a pretty broad topic, so I suspect that some questions go unanswered because we don't have anyone with the right expertise. If you know an expert in the field of an unanswered question, please show it to them, in the hope that they'll come to the site and answer it!

Comment: With "too hard" TCS questions, we can also propose migrating to [cstheory.SE] to the asker and the mods there, and migrate if both agree.

Comment: fyi migration on stackexchange seems to usually happen without asking the asker, just with moderator choice. seems like esp if there are no answers so far, thats a reasonable/fair policy

Comment: @vzn Migration happens without asker consent only if the question is offtopic here. We have been saying since the beginning that we won't migrate away ontopic questions without consent, not won't we ask other sites to migrate questions they can handle to us. Migrating a question to math.SE or cstheory.SE does not make sense if the asker is not interested in an answer they could get there.

Comment: @raphael dont have issue with that. something to keep in mind however is that statistically unless a question gets an answer in a few days (when its on front page), it will almost never get an answer; this is prob true across most stackexchange sites. and the asker is surely going to prefer an answer to no answer and so migrating after the 1st few days without an answer can prob only benefit the asker. the only exception would be if the comments help...

Comment: @vzn I have open questions myself that I don't want to be migrated, so there's your counter example. Asking costs us nothing, so there is no reason not to. (Unfortunately, old questions *are* routinely forgotten, but not always.)

Comment: For the record, if you want to exclude closed questions from your search, do [`answers:0 closed:0`](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3A0)

Comment: @Raphael which reminds me: we've been leaving closed questions to fester for a while, we need to delete more stuff.

Comment: @Gilles Should we have an event for that, or do you think we should just do it more?

Comment: @Raphael The first one was a bust (one question edited IIRC), but we can try again...

Answer (score 3):

We did a [meetup to answer open questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/457/98) before, but not many people attended (or seemed to care at all).

If we did a similar thing again, who would join in?

Comment: I will try to join. I went over the open question and tried to answer a few, but more importantly, I voted to close a few, that doesn't seem to be answerable. Maybe this should be discussed as well.

Comment: Another idea, is to pick, say, 3-5 unanswered question a day, and try to work on them, but mainly - popping them from the forgotten archives into the top of the front page.

Comment: @RanG. The idea of the event was to do exactly that: check out the questions, improve them if necessary, answer if possible and close of not. I for one could maybe manage one closed question a day, but that would be steep. I think an event would make more sense; it would also help us form a closer community. (Chat is *deserted* these days!)

Comment: Raphael, I think it is time for another event. (;