# Encouraging multiple answers to questions

Tags: discussion, answers

As a follow up to Yuval's post about [the percentage of answered questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/533/percentage-of-answered-questions) probably we should do something to encourage [more answers to questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science) to increase the answer ratio of the site. Any opinions or ideas on this?

Comment: Among all science SE sites in beta, the average number of answers per question is distributed in [1.5,2.6], with average 1.9 and median 1.8. Our current value is 1.8. The non-beta sites have {1.9, 2.4, 2.3, 2.0}.

Comment: I think one of the issues is the excessive use of comments. If any (answer-like) comment would've become an answer, and the voting system would've differentiate the good answers from the partial- comment-like- answers, the beta numbers would be up. Is this what we want? Not sure.

Comment: @RanG., Which is made all the funnier that your post is a comment ;)

Comment: @RanG. We can definitely ask people to post answers when we think they have comment what amounts to one.