# "Answer the Un-answered" Event! (27 January 2013)

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Following the discussion in [Percentage of answered questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/533/157), we organize an event which is dedicated to answering the (~200) [un-answered](https://cs.stackexchange.com/unanswered) questions we have on CS.SE.

We'll be coordinating the event [in the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science).

This question on meta is meant to become the announcement of the event, once we set all the details (consider it as CW and feel free to edit). 
**Please upvote this question if you intend to participate in the event** so we'd have a rough estimation for the amount of participants.

Proposed date: Sunday, 27 January 2013
Let's try to hold a kickoff meeting at 9:00 UTC (10:00 CET, Saturday 11pm EST, Saturday 8pm PST).
Also - let's try to meet for short concluding on Monday, 28 January at 12am UTC (1am CET, Sunday 7pm EST, Sunday 4pm PST).

Agenda:

1. Questions that do have answers but those are not-upvoted. Can those answers be verified/improved and upvoted?
2. Questions that have comments that give a possible/partial answer - convert comments into an answer (CW answer?).
3. Questions that are cross-posted - consider closing (especially if answered in the sister SE).
4. Re-examine the other questions: clarify if not clear, close if off-topic, etc.
5. Finally, promote good questions that are still unanswered:

   - Make those question pop-up to the front page by making a small edit, or is there another way?).
   - Optionally, set bounties to the most interesting questions.

Comment: Excellent idea! Unfortunately I won't be able to participate as it's a bit early for me on week-ends. Maybe on a later occurrence of this event.

Comment: @Khaur note that the event lasts almost the entire day; feel free to jump in anytime - I hope that at least 2-3 people will be there at any given moment..

Comment: I hope I'll find the time to pick a couple of questions I care about... :/

Comment: We're up to 91%!

Comment: Why not just prod people to look for high-voted, unanswered questions on a continuous basis? On their favorite tags, perhaps?